# regex for characters

Tags: c#, regex

In C# i'm using RegexValidator to validate a field which can contains only L,l,M,m,D,d values.
I tried to use [RegexValidator("[l|L][M|m][D|d]" ... , but this does not work.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This regex:

```
[l|L][M|m][D|d]
```

means:

- l, | or L; then
- M, | or m; then
- D, | or d.

Try:

```
^[LMD]+$
```

as a case insensitive match if you can do that or:

```
^[LlMmDd]+$
```

if you can't.

Both of these require the whole string to match a sequence of L, l, M, m, D or d characters. Use `+` to mean one or more if it can't be empty or `*` to mean 0 or more if it's allowed to be empty.

**Edit:** based on the updated information, if you want to allow one of those characters and only one of those then:

```
^[LlMmDd]$
```

Comment: so it's allowed only L or l, M or m, D or d. No other combinations. And at least 1 character and no more than 1.

Comment: @qwerty: please explain further. You mean they can only enter 1 of those 6 characters? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, they can enter only one of those 6 characters. And btw, RegexValidator works only for string, but if i'm using this Regex, this can be user for char attributes? Or in case of a char property how should i write a regexValidator?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use inversion. check the field for characters not in your defined list.

```
/[^LlMmDd]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you can try something like this

```
var s1 = "Ll";
var s2 = "m";
var s3 = "LmD";
var pattern = "^[LMD]$";

Console.WriteLine( Regex.IsMatch(s1, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) );
Console.WriteLine( Regex.IsMatch(s2, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) );
Console.WriteLine( Regex.IsMatch(s3, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) );
```

Writes the following to the console

> False
>   True
>   False

You can only use Regex on string but you could always convert your char

```
char c = 'd';
Console.WriteLine( Regex.IsMatch(new String(c,1), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on regexp. You should be able to Google (or Bing) on tutorials of regexp.

`[asdf]` means one and only one and not less than one char which is either `a`, `s`, `d` or `f`.
`[asdf]*` means any number of characters but they must be either be `a`, `s`, `d` or `f`.
`[asdf]+` means at least one character and they must either be `a`, `s`, `d` or `f`.

Regexp does not use the `|` character as an OR operator in within a `[]` square bracket character definition constraint.

`[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]` means a String that must have the first character uppercase alphabet (any uppercase char between A to Z) followed by at least one lowercase alphabet (any lowercase char between `a` to `z`) and terminated by a decimal digit.

`[l|L][M|m][D|d]` means the string must have exactly 3 chars.
First char must be either `l`, `|` or `L`.
2nd char must be either `M`, `|` or `m`.
3rd char must be either `D`, `|` or `d`.

`[lL][Mm][Dd]` may be what you want to use.
`[lLMmDd]+` for a string of at least one char constrained to be either `l`, `L`, `M`, `m`, `D` or `d`.
`[lLMmDd][lLMmDd][lLMmDd]+` for a string of at least 3 chars long where all chars are constrained to be either `l`, `L`, `M`, `m`, `D` or `d`.

Answer (score 0):

This code should read a string from the console, and match it. It should accept only 1 character, and matches with the characters you provided.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[L|M|D]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Text");
        String str = System.Console.ReadLine();
        Match match = regex.Match(str);

        if (match.Success == true)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Fail");
        }
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
```